# Assigning of value in a for loop on a mouse event

Tags: javascript, loops

Why do I always get the last value assigned to the variable
even though I already enclosed it in a function?

When the event mouse up is triggered and getGoogleFiles is called, the last value assigned to resourceId is called. I don't get it.

```
for ( var i in arrayObj) {
 var resourceId = arrayObj[i].ResourceId;
 entity_list.onmouseup = function(event) {
    parent.changeButtonState(this, event);
    (function(resourceId) {
        getGoogleFiles(resourceId);
    })(resourceId);
 }
}
```

Note: This is different to other JavaScript questions because the onmouseup is not triggered

I followed the creating of another function mentioned here:
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

```
for ( var i in arrayObj) {
 entity_list.onmouseup = function(event) {
  parent.changeButtonState(this, event);
  testing(arrayObj[i].ResourceId);
 }
}

function testing(index){
   return function() { getGoogleFiles(index); };
}
```

But when the element of "entity_list" is triggered, nothing happens. 
I can't use `let` because the specific browser that I'm using returns a SyntaxError

`SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode`

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post how did you do your loop?

Comment: @Radonirina Maminiaina I edited and added the for loop part

Comment: Don't use `var`. Use `let` instead.

Comment: @Ceving I can't use let because I get a Syntax error in the specific browser that I'm using

Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `testing()` to create the listener function, not something you call inside it.

```js
for (var i in arrayObj) {
  entity_list.onmouseup = testing(arrayObj[i].ResourceId, parent);
}

function testing(index, parent) {
  return function(event) {
    parent.changeButtonState(this, event);
    getGoogleFiles(index);
  };
}
```

But you wouldn't have to go through any of this if you use `forEach()` instead of a `for` loop, since it creates a new scope for `obj` in each iteration.

```js
arrayObj.forEach(function(obj) {
  entity_list.onmouseup = function(event) {
    parent.changeButtonState(this, event);
    testing(obj.ResourceId);
  }
});
```

Comment: OMG! Why didn't I think of that! Thank you @Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a *var scoped* variable here.
But you could assign the `resourceId` to a [data attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) on the relative html element, so you can read it when the event fires.

```js
var arrayObj = [{ResourceId: "test1"}, {ResourceId: "test2"}, {ResourceId: "test3"}];

var entity_list = document.getElementsByClassName("entity_list");

for ( var i in arrayObj) {
 entity_list[i].dataset.resourceId = arrayObj[i].ResourceId;
 entity_list[i].onmouseup = function(event) {
    getGoogleFiles(this.dataset.resourceId);
 }
}

function getGoogleFiles(resourceId) {
  console.log(resourceId);
}
```

```html
<span class="entity_list">entity list (item 1)</span>
<span class="entity_list">entity list (item 2)</span>
<span class="entity_list">entity list (item 3)</span>
```